# Validate email address and cell phone number field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have below script:

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var full_name = $("#full_name").val();
        var cell_phone = $("#cell_phone").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var dataString = 'full_name='+ full_name + '&cell_phone=' + cell_phone + '&email=' + email;
        if (full_name=='' || cell_phone=='' || email=='')
        {   
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();      
        }   
        else 
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "join.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('.submit').fadeIn(200).hide();
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

1. How to make validate email.
2. Only ( **numbers** **+** **-** ) and not less than 7 numbers for cell_phone filed.

Comment: 1 `<input type=email>`

Comment: another option is simple regular expressions

Comment: email validation at its finest using regex
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmuXqZi3r5M

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate email address in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: And the [phone](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18375929/4454454)

Comment: Hi @MaxZoom .... How to use your suggestion code with my script ???

Comment: Hi @dandavis .... I get alert if email is wrong  but when submit the data insert to database :(

Answer (score 0):

[is.js](http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/)'s [email](http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/#email) and [phone](http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/#eppPhone) validators can be solution.

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit").click(function() {
        var full_name = $("#full_name").val();
        var cell_phone = $("#cell_phone").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var dataString = 'full_name='+ full_name + '&cell_phone=' + cell_phone + '&email=' + email;
        if (full_name=='' || is.not.eppPhone(cell_phone) || is.not.email(email))
        {   
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();      
        }   
        else 
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "join.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('.submit').fadeIn(200).hide();
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i;
var phoneno = /^\+?(?:[0-9] ?){6,14}[0-9]$/;
if (full_name=='' || !phoneno.test(cell_phone) || !re.test(email))
```