# Validate phone number with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate phone number with javascript, so far i have regex that looks like this:

`/^[0-9\+]{8,13}$/`

But it is not what i finally wanna get. 
I need get phone number format that is default for my country "Poland". For example few phones formats i need check with regex if user correctly passed them: `321123321`, `123-321-123`, `123 321 123`, `123211212`, `12-321-12-12`, `12 321 12 12`.

Sorry if my question is silly but i have no idea how to understand this regex.

Comment: _it is ok but i need something more_ What is something more?

Comment: @bub look under text you quoted

Comment: Or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375929/validate-phone-number-using-javascript) or _insert one of the tons of duplicates here_

Comment: @mdziekon nope i need regex to look something difrent but dunno how to make it.

Comment: @kuchar I don't see anything!

Comment: @bub well its good that other ppl see it...

Comment: This is just spoon feed me laziness, writing something without any explantations, other ppl should understand what you mean ;)

Comment: @bub i think they understand if i got two correct answers...

Comment: @bub when writing the topic title he gets [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338267/validate-phone-number-with-javascript) in the possible duplicates suggestions. But stackoverflow doesn't punish this, people even on average get rep for these threads.

Comment: @ASDFGerte you should also take a look [this tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how my friend:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are allowing digits spaces and hypens.

Why don't you remove spaces and hyphens and check if rest of them are digits or not.

```
var str = "123 321 123";
str = str.replace( /\s|-/g, "" );
```

Now run your own regex on it

```
"123 321 123".replace( /\s|-/g, "" ).match(/^[0-9\+]{8,13}$/)
```

Or simply include space and hyphen in the regex

```
"123 321 123".match(/^[0-9\+\s-]{8,13}$/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below regex which will allow - and blank space and all the characters should be between 8 and 13.

```
^[0-9\s- \+]{8,13}$
```