# Mob. number validation in js CRM2016

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-online

I'm using below code for accepting +xxxxxxxxx format but I'm getting error like Cannot read property 'match' of undefined at phonenumber Can you plz suggest me where I'm committing mistake ;

Below code:

```
function phonenumber() {
    var inputtxt = Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_phonenumber").getValue();
    var phoneno = /^+?([0-9]{2}))?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
    if (inputtxt.match(phoneno)) {
        return true;
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_phonenumber").clearNotification();
    } else {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_phonenumber").setNotification("Format error");
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'm refreing this :[Validate phone number using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375929/validate-phone-number-using-javascript/42265630#42265630)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure `inputtxt` is not null (as in when the field is empty).

Something like

```
if (inputtxt && inputtxt.match(phoneno))
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: FYI the fact that this is CRM is not actually relevant to the question :)