# Java form validation For my Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an alert box which will output the details from the form I am now wondering how I start the Java validation part so that if the form is filled in 
correctly an alert box with the form details will show however if it is wrong instruct the user to fill in the invalid boxes.

HTML

```
 <form id="foo" onsubmit="formAlert(); return false;" method="POST">
    <p><label for="first_name">First Name<label><input type="text" id="first_name" value="" /></p>
    <p><label for="last_name">Last Name<label><input type="text" id="last_name" value="" /></p>
     <p><label for="Phone_num">Phone Number<label><input type="number" id="phone_num" value="" /></p>


    <p><input type="submit" value="click me" onclick=""/></p>
</form>
```

Java Script

```
 function formAlert() {
alert_string = '';
var userName = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
var userLastName = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
 var phoneno =  document.getElementById('phone_num').value;
if(userName === "" || userName === null){
  alert("Please enter name");
}
if(userLastName === "" || userLastName === null){
  alert("Please enter lastname");
}
```

else if(phoneno === "/^(?([0-9]{3}))?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;" || phoneno === null){
      alert("Please enter Phone number");
    }

```
else{
 alert_string += userName + " ";
 alert_string += userLastName;
 alert_string += phoneno;
 alert(alert_string);
```

}
}

Comment: Some punctuation of the question would make reading easier. There are [*many questions on form validation already*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+form+validation), what have you tried?

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: So add if statements to check if they are valid or use html5 validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick and simple solution. Add this to your javascript code. Hope it helps!

```
function validatePhone(inputtxt) {
 var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
 return phoneno.test(inputtxt)
 }

 function formAlert() {
  alert_string = '';
 var userName = document.getElementById('first_name').value;
 var userLastName = document.getElementById('last_name').value;
 var phoneno =  document.getElementById('phone_num').value;
 if(userName === "" || userName === null){
 alert("Please enter name");
 }
 if(userLastName === "" || userLastName === null){
 alert("Please enter lastname");
 }
else if(!validatePhone(phoneno)){ alert("Please enter 10 digits for phone  number"); }

else{
alert_string += userName + " ";
alert_string += userLastName + " ";
alert_string += phoneno;
alert(alert_string);
 } 
}
```

To check for email simple use required. Something like this:

```
<input type="email" name="email" required>
```

There are many ways to validate phone number. Here's a good example: Credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18376246/4084160

Comment: Thanks for the help it works well could you help me with the Phone number and email verification please, in an example such as the above solution you have done.

Comment: @Jamesanderson if you want to check for email simply use required. I'm updating my solution now

Comment: For my website I have to use Java validation , but thanks for the help you are providing it has been highly useful.

Comment: all done pal how would I go about verifying a number ?

Comment: There are so many ways to do a validation for phone number. I'm updating my solution right now. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for everything just the help I need wish I could give two thumbs up.

Comment: bro I tried to do the phone number validation but I think i did it wrong just updated my code i think i put the validation in the wrong place

Comment: ignore the previous comment lol its working now thank you, so if i do the same for the email it should work ?

Comment: Yes you can use Regex for email too. Here are some examples. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: it worked brilliantly thank you for the help I have been trying to find a solution for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

There is other way to do that. it is a good approach if you have many inputs

```
<html>

<style>
.required 
{
    border: 1px solid #F00;
    padding: 2px;
}
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="foo" onsubmit="formAlert(); return false;" method="POST">
        <p><label for="first_name">First Name<label><input                    type="text" id="first_name" value="" /></p>
        <p><label for="last_name">Last Name<label><input type="text"          id="last_name" value="" /></p>

        <p><input type="submit" value="click me" onclick=""/></p>
    </form>

    <div id="msgRequired" style="display: none;">
    <p>required Field!</p>
    </div>

<script>    

function formAlert() {
        alert_string = '';
        var cont = 0;
         $("#foo input").not(':hidden').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass("required");
            cont++;
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass("required");
        }
    });
        if(cont == 0)
        {

        alert_string = alert_string + document.getElementById('first_name').value;
        alert_string = alert_string + ' ';
        alert_string = alert_string + document.getElementById('last_name').value;

        alert(alert_string);
        $("#msgRequired").hide();
        }
        else
        {
        $("#msgRequired").show();
        }

       }
</script>   

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution pal could you show me how to verify an email address or phone number.

Comment: the solution that @HenryDev Replied, is a good way to Validate.