# How can I validate check for a phone number?

Tags: javascript, html, string, validation, if-statement

```
let phoneNumber = $('#order-phone').val()

if (phoneNumber.length == 13) {
    parts = phoneNumber.split('-');
    if ((parts[0] == '010') && ((parts[1] >= '0000') && (parts[1] <= '9999')) && ((parts[2] >= '0000') && (parts[2] <= '9999'))) {
        alert('Finished');
    } else {
        alert('Put your number like "010-OOOO-OOOO"');
    }
} else {
    alert('Put your number like "010-OOOO-OOOO"')
}
```

The situation is like..
The user inputs his phone number as string and then I check the validation for the phone number the user gave to me.
'PhoneNumber' above is string type and I don't know how can I do perfect validate check for the strings that is phone number with 13 characters including numeric characters and hyphen.

Comment: https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md

Comment: you can use regex

Comment: This is what you're looking for,
<br />
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375929/validate-phone-number-using-javascript

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It seems to work fine. You _could_ combine the length and parts tests so you don't have to repeat the alert... `if (phoneNumber.length == 13 && ((parts[0] == '010') && ((parts[1] >= '0000') && (parts[1] <= '9999')) && ((parts[2] >= '0000') && (parts[2] <= '9999')))) {`

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript regex for validation. The length check is not necessary, the regex will take care of that. The regex below is the global regex for phone number validation. For your check the regex should be option-4 from other regex.
This is the code:

```
let phoneNumber = $('#order-phone').val();
let patt = new RegExp(/^[+]*[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{10}$/g); //This is the regex for validation phone number
let res = patt.test(phoneNumber );
console.log(res); //this will return true or false

//alert(res);
```

Other regex:

1. /^[+]*[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{10}$/g : +XXX-XXXXXXXXXX ('+' is optional)
2. /^[+]*010-[0-9]{10}$/g : +010-XXXXXXXXXX ('+' is optional)
3. /^[0-9]{3}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{4}[-]{0,1}[0-9]{4}$/g : XXX-XXXX-XXXX ('-' is optional)
4. /^[0-9]{3}[-]{1}[0-9]{4}[-]{1}[0-9]{4}$/g : XXX-XXXX-XXXX.

Comment: OP seems to want to allow the `010` prefix _only_, so not `{1,4}` if that's true.